# How can I get perl MongoDB Admin module

Tags: mongodb, perl

I am trying the Mongodb admin module from CPAN 
https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::Admin

The exact sample code does not work , because the module does not have a MongoDB::Connection package

This is the script I am trying

```
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::Admin;

my $connection = MongoDB::Connection->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
my $admin = MongoDB::Admin->new('connection' => $connection);

my $ops = $admin->current_op();
```

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB::Admin](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::Admin) seems to be out of date. If you look at the [MongoDB driver changelog](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/MongoDB#L764) you can see that at version 1.0 the MongoDB::Connection was dropped because it was deprecated.

> - The long-deprecated MongoDB::Connection class has been removed.

The latest version of MongoDB::Admin is 0.03 from July 2011. At that point, MongoDB was at version 0.43, but is now on 2.0.3. A lot has happened since then.

You might want to look for a different graphical user interface.

Comment: I have no idea @Ram. I have never used MongoDB.